# ChangingTable Structure in FuelPHP with Oil CLI

Tags: php, fuelphp

I created a table using oil generate CLI command and the table was created as required.

```
php oil generate scaffold <details>
```

Now I wanted to change few columns and add a new column to the table strcutre. I used the oil refine and it ran.

```
php oil refine migrate -all
```

But there is no changes done to the table. Migration details are provided below (chnage of a column - 'created').

**Old migration file:** 003_create_categories.php

```
<?php

namespace Fuel\Migrations;

class Create_categories
{
    public function up()
    {
    \DBUtil::create_table('categories', array(
        'id' => array('constraint' => 11, 'type' => 'int', 'auto_increment' => true, 'unsigned' => true),
        'name' => array('constraint' => 255, 'type' => 'varchar'),
        'description' => array('type' => 'text'),
        'image' => array('constraint' => 255, 'type' => 'varchar'),
        'created' => array('type' => 'datetime'),
        'created_at' => array('constraint' => 11, 'type' => 'int', 'null' => true),
        'updated_at' => array('constraint' => 11, 'type' => 'int', 'null' => true),

    ), array('id'));
    }

    public function down() {
    \DBUtil::drop_table('categories');
    }
}
```

**New migration file:** 004_create_categories.php

```
<?php

namespace Fuel\Migrations;

class Create_categories
{
    public function up()
    {
    \DBUtil::create_table('categories', array(
        'id' => array('constraint' => 11, 'type' => 'int', 'auto_increment' => true, 'unsigned' => true),
        'name' => array('constraint' => 255, 'type' => 'varchar'),
        'description' => array('type' => 'text'),
        'image' => array('constraint' => 255, 'type' => 'varchar'),
        'status' => array('type' => 'tinyint'),
        'created_at' => array('constraint' => 11, 'type' => 'int', 'null' => true),
        'updated_at' => array('constraint' => 11, 'type' => 'int', 'null' => true),

    ), array('id'));
    }

    public function down() {
    \DBUtil::drop_table('categories');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migration files are designed to build on each other. You don't need to create the table in every migration. Fuel will run your `003` migration, and then your `004` migration which will fail because the table already exists.

Your `004` migration should only contain a description of how to update the table from its previous state. Ie, add your new column.

The "down" of your migration should do the opposite as well. So your `004` migration's `down` should remove the column.

Comment: Is there any example link or sample to understand it better? I mean about the fuelPHP way of saying to update and remove the column..

Comment: I finally did that after some trouble and issues. But I see that the model is not updated as per the new migration with the new column? Is that correct?

Comment: The documentation for the DB/DBUtil classes should have all the information you need. The migrations are only for migrating your database, or other data storing files (updating static caches or what have you), they should not be for modifying your code.